# Setting Up Subdomain In Ubuntu 10.04 server

Tags: subdomain, virtualhost

I am not able to setup subdomain through virtual host in my ubuntu server. Followed following steps

in /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1 localhost
10.0.0.1 domain.com
10.0.0.1 sub.domain.com

in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ i created two files domain.com and sub.domain.com

in domain.com file,

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
 ServerName domain.com
 ServerAlias www.domain.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/
 ErrorLog /var/www/domain.com/logs/error.log
 CustomLog /var/www/domain.com/logs/access.log combined (all these folders exists)
 </VirtualHost>
```

in sub.domain.com file,

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@sub.domain.com
 ServerName sub.domain.com
 ServerAlias www.sub.domain.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/sub.domain.com/
 ErrorLog /var/www/sub.domain.com/logs/error.log
 CustomLog /var/www/sub.domain.com/logs/access.log combined (all these folders exists)
 </VirtualHost>
```

After this is i enabled the site by a2ensite domain.com, a2ensite sub.domain.com and then restarted apache server.

Domain.com works fine. But sub.domain.com is not working. I am getting error "Webpage not available".

Can anyone tell me what is the mistake i am doing??

Comment: Have you correct A DNS record for sub.domain.com?

Comment: No. should i change anything in /etc/resolv.conf. How can i add a DNS record for sub.domain.com